I need to compare 2 files, a Pdf and an excel file to spot the differences in data
My code seems to work correctly for the added status, each is in its own individual line, but the deleted status is concatenated into one long unreadable string. I need each difference to be in its own individual row, and would like for this to be exported into an excel file as well as a word file. Also for future purposes I would like to add files dynamically instead of being hard coded
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import difflib
import re
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from docx import Document

# Function to extract text from PDF using PyPDF2
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, "rb") as file:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(file)
        text = ""
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    return text

# Function to read Excel file and return a list of rows
def read_excel(excel_path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
        return [row.tolist() for _, row in df.iterrows()]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Excel file not found.")
        return []

# Function to clean text data
def clean_text(text):
    # Remove any characters that are not printable ASCII or illegal in Excel
    cleaned_text = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isprintable() or x.isspace() or ord(x) > 31, text))
    # Replace any problematic characters with an empty string
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^\x20-\x7E]', '', cleaned_text)
    return cleaned_text

# Function to find differences between two texts
def find_differences(text1, text2):
    diff = difflib.ndiff(text1.splitlines(), text2.splitlines())
    diff_data = []
    current_deleted_text = ""
    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('+'):
            if current_deleted_text:
                diff_data.append({"Text": current_deleted_text.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
                current_deleted_text = ""
            diff_data.append({"Text": line[2:], "Status": "Added"})
        elif line.startswith('-'):
            current_deleted_text += line[2:] + "\n"
        else:
            if current_deleted_text:
                diff_data.append({"Text": current_deleted_text.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
                current_deleted_text = ""
            diff_data.append({"Text": line[2:], "Status": "Matched"})
    if current_deleted_text:
        diff_data.append({"Text": current_deleted_text.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
    return diff_data


# Define the PDF and Excel file paths
pdf_path = "pdf_name.pdf"
excel_path = 'excel_name'

# Extract text from Excel
excel_rows = read_excel(excel_path)

# Extract text from PDF
pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)

# Clean the PDF text
pdf_text_cleaned = clean_text(pdf_text)

# Find differences between PDF and Excel files
diff_data = find_differences(pdf_text_cleaned, '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in excel_rows]))

# Create a DataFrame to store the differences
diff_df = pd.DataFrame(diff_data, columns=["Text", "Status"])

# Define colors for highlighting
highlight_colors = {'Added': '#00FF00', 'Deleted': '#FF0000', 'Matched': '#FFFFFF'}  # Green for Added, Red for Deleted, White for Matched

# Export to Excel with highlighting
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter("differences.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
diff_df.to_excel(excel_writer, index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
workbook = excel_writer.book
worksheet = excel_writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add cell formats for highlighting
for status, color in highlight_colors.items():
    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': color})
    # Find cells with the specified status and apply the cell format
    for row_idx, row in diff_df.iterrows():
        if row['Status'] == status:
            worksheet.set_row(row_idx + 1, None, cell_format)

# Save the Excel file
excel_writer._save()

# Export to CSV
diff_df.to_csv("differences.csv", index=False)

# Function to convert CSV to XML
def csv_to_xml(csv_file, xml_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    root = Element('Differences')
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        diff = SubElement(root, 'Difference')
        text = SubElement(diff, 'Text')
        text.text = row['Text']
        status = SubElement(diff, 'Status')
        status.text = row['Status']
    xml_data = tostring(root)
    xml_str = parseString(xml_data).toprettyxml()
    with open(xml_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(xml_str)

# Function to generate Word document from XML
def xml_to_docx(xml_file, docx_file):
    doc = Document()
    tree = ElementTree.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for diff in root.findall('Difference'):
        text = diff.find('Text').text
        status = diff.find('Status').text
        if status == 'Added':
            doc.add_paragraph(text).bold = True
        elif status == 'Deleted':
            doc.add_paragraph(text).italic = True
        else:
            doc.add_paragraph(text)
    doc.save(docx_file)

# Convert CSV to XML
csv_file = 'differences.csv'
xml_file = 'differences.xml'
csv_to_xml(csv_file, xml_file)

# Read CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('differences.csv')

# Create a new Word document
doc = Document()

# Add a table to the document
table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
table.style = 'Table Grid'

# Add header row to the table
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Text'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Status'

# Add each difference as a row in the table
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = row['Text']
    row_cells[1].text = row['Status']

# Save the document using a context manager
with open('differences.docx', 'wb') as f:
    doc.save(f)

print("Word document created successfully.")


I want the differences to be in its own individual row, and to be highlighted with its corresponding colour for its status

Your issue might come from the way you handle deleted text by just adding text and line breaks to a single string with current_deleted_text += line[2:] + "\n", and then adding a row to diff_data with : diff_data.append({"Text": current_deleted_text.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
Try doing this :
if current_deleted_text:
    for s in current_deleted_text.split('\n')[:-1]:
        diff_data.append({"Text": s.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})

Instead of this :
if current_deleted_text:
    diff_data.append({"Text": current_deleted_text.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})

The [:-1] ensures that you don't get an empty Deleted row because of the last string you add to current_deleted_text.
Does this help ?
Edit : add test case
function is now :
def find_differences(text1, text2):
    diff = difflib.ndiff(text1.splitlines(), text2.splitlines())
    diff_data = []
    current_deleted_text = ""
    for line in diff:
        print(f"line: {line}")
        if line.startswith('+'):
            if current_deleted_text:
                if current_deleted_text:
                    for s in current_deleted_text.split('\n')[:-1]:
                        diff_data.append({"Text": s.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
                current_deleted_text = ""
            diff_data.append({"Text": line[2:], "Status": "Added"})
        elif line.startswith('-'):
            current_deleted_text += line[2:] + "\n"
        else:
            if current_deleted_text:
                if current_deleted_text:
                    for s in current_deleted_text.split('\n')[:-1]:
                        diff_data.append({"Text": s.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
                current_deleted_text = ""
            diff_data.append({"Text": line[2:], "Status": "Matched"})
    if current_deleted_text:
        if current_deleted_text:
            for s in current_deleted_text.split('\n')[:-1]:
                diff_data.append({"Text": s.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"})
    return diff_data

and with two test strings :
text1 = """Hello world
Deleted line.
Other deleted.
Other matched line here."""

text2 = """Hello world
Added line.
New line added.
Other matched line here."""

Result with modified function :
for diff in differences:
    print(f"{diff['Status']}: {diff['Text']}")

Matched: Hello world
Deleted: Deleted line.
Deleted: Other deleted.
Added: Added line.
Added: New line added.
Matched: Other matched line here.

Result with original function :
for diff in differences:
    print(f"{diff['Status']}: {diff['Text']}")

Matched: Hello world
Deleted: Deleted line.
Other deleted.
Added: Added line.
Added: New line added.
Matched: Other matched line here.

See how the two deleted lines are really just one entry ?

This actually removed my Deleted data for some reason ?

Did you replace all occurrences of diff_data.append({"Text": current_deleted_text.strip(), "Status": "Deleted"}) ?
function works for me with two test strings

@SlavNevsky i updated my answer to show differences

Thanks for all the help, but Im still really struggling with my project, to give you an idea, the lists of data I am comparing is over 15 000 lines

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, the method I gave you will work with any number of lines.
